# c# Order By on List of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list/collection of objects with multiple fields. One of them being filename.

I am sorting based on filename but not getting the correct results.

List:

```
"552939_VVIDEO9.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO8.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO13.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO12.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO7.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO6.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO2.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO16.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO10.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO3.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO11.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO4.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO1.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO15.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO14.mp4"
"552939_VVIDEO17.mp4"


  List<WfVideo> orderVideo = ProductData.Videos.OrderBy(o => o.Filename, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Result I am getting:

```
VOD1
VOD2
VVIDEO1
VVIDEO10
VVIDEO11
VVIDEO12
VVIDEO13
VVIDEO14
VVIDEO15
VVIDEO16
VVIDEO17
VVIDEO2
VVIDEO3
VVIDEO4
VVIDEO5
VVIDEO6
```

Is the sorting incorrect?

Comment: ASCII speaking , it is ordered correctly..

Comment: What exactly in incorrect? How do you want it to be sorted?

Comment: That ordering looks correct to me.  You asked for invariant culture, ignore case, and "10" is less than "3" in that collation. What ordering do you want? If you want the ordering where numbers are sorted by their numeric value and not their text, do a search for "C# natural sort" and you'll find other questions about that. If that is your question, then this one should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort these files after the number only, you could pass a Comparer to Sort that implements the rules you want. This sorts the filenames according to their number:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>
    {
        "552939_VVIDEO9.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO8.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO13.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO12.mp4",
        "VOD1.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO6.mp4",
        "VOD2.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO2.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO16.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO10.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO3.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO11.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO4.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO1.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO15.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO14.mp4",
        "552939_VVIDEO17.mp4"
    };
        files.Sort((a, b) => {
            int an = 0;
            int bn = 1;
            var regex = new Regex("([0-9]+).mp4", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var aGroups = regex.Match(a).Groups;
            var bGroups = regex.Match(b).Groups;
            var aidx = aGroups.Count > 1 ? 1 : 0;
            var bidx = bGroups.Count > 1 ? 1 : 0;
            an = int.Parse(aGroups[aidx].Value);
            bn = int.Parse(bGroups[bidx].Value); 
            if (an == bn)
                return 0;
            if (an < bn)
                return -1;
            return 1;
        });
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
VOD1.mp4
552939_VVIDEO1.mp4
VOD2.mp4
552939_VVIDEO2.mp4
552939_VVIDEO3.mp4
552939_VVIDEO4.mp4
552939_VVIDEO6.mp4
552939_VVIDEO8.mp4
552939_VVIDEO9.mp4
552939_VVIDEO10.mp4
552939_VVIDEO11.mp4
552939_VVIDEO12.mp4
552939_VVIDEO13.mp4
552939_VVIDEO14.mp4
552939_VVIDEO15.mp4
552939_VVIDEO16.mp4
552939_VVIDEO17.mp4
```

Note some additional error checking may be needed. You can offcourse extend this Comparer function to work for whatever rules you wish.

Comment: They dont, original post mentions VOD and VVIdeo

Comment: Then you just change the rules inside the Comparer. See my updated answer.

Comment: Should be vod1, vod2, then preceeding by videos. I managed to take your first part of code and alter it to my needs. Thanks